# How to get avatar for gmail user?

Tags: javascript, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, avatar

I'm creating an email-based application in React with the Gmail API. I'm loading in a bunch of messages, and I want to display avatars of the senders.

I'm using [this package](https://github.com/Sitebase/react-avatar) to display avatars. I'd like to either have a Google Id or an image url. It would also be nice to be able to get images for other popular services, such as Outlook and Yahoo mail.

Other people have asked this same question, but all the answers either seem to use the Picasa API (which is deprecated) or the Google+ API (which will be deprecated).

**EDIT:** Yes, the `react-avatar` package claims it can find an avatar based on supplied user data, but all it does with the email is find a Gravatar, which many people don't have.

Comment: Maybe you can use Firebase Authentication?

Comment: @NoobTW No thank you. I'd rather stick with the plain old Gmail API, especially since we've built a lot based on it. Also, does Firebase Auth even support Gmail APIs? I've always thought it's just for login.

Comment: Will this not get you what you want: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/photos/get

Comment: @LanceWhatley I believe that api is limited to searching the users of a particular G Suite domain

Comment: @cody Yeah, I think so.

Comment: It used to be available via the Google+ API, but it was shutdown due to security
see: https://www.blog.google/technology/safety-security/project-strobe/

There isn't an anonymous way

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**What you want to do is not possible via the GMAIL API or any other Google API**

You can not take a Google email address and search for the image or any other personal profile information associated with that email address via any Google API endpoint. Explanation below.

**Get image of the sender of an email**

Gmail API lists the email messages that have been sent to and by a user. The gmail API is basically returning the mail server email message response in MIME format which if you check does not contain a profile image. It does **not** return to you the image of a the sender or the reciever.

Google does not have endpoint for developers to use to searching on a gmail.com email address and returning any user profile information (including image) this would be against the users privacy.  A user would have to grant you permission to see their image and you dont have that permission for every gmail user who may be sending emails to your authenticated user.

The gmail website probably does some kind of check on gmail email addresses and puts the picture on attached with the account.  Google has access to the profile data of all GMAIL users, google cant give you this same access as it would be against the users privacy.   If its not a gmail account they may check [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/) to see if an image has been set up for this email address.  Again there is no way for you to request the image of a google user using their email address.

- You could check Gravatar to see if one had been set up for that email
- If the authenticated user has added this user as a contact and has added a picture for this user you may be able to use the [People api](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list).

In the past i have recommend to users that as an image they take the first letter of the users email address and create an image using that letter.   You may also want to use a question mark which is actually what gmail does when its website cant find an email from the user probably by checking Gravatar.

[image]

**Get image of current authenticated user**

You can get this information from the [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) endpoint just make sure that you have requested the profile scope from the user when you authenticate them

```
GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me
```

It returns a large response containing the users profile information part of it contains the users picture

```
"photos": [
    {
      "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mDuIWqXzrrp-65cIhXSD2HjCI8WYsWHR0fDx5_wQPY=s100", 
      "metadata": {
        "source": {
          "type": "PROFILE", 
          "id": "117200475532672775346"
        }, 
        "primary": true
      }
    }
  ],
```

The offical sample project for [people api](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/js) contains information on how to connect to the api.   Just make sure to add the 'profile' scope

The code to get the picture should be something like this.

```
function getPicture() {
        gapi.client.people.people.get({
           'resourceName': 'people/me',
           'pageSize': 10,
           'personFields': 'photos',
         }).then(function(response) {
           var connections = response.result.connections;
           appendPre('Connections:');

           if (connections.length > 0) {
             for (i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
               var person = connections[i];
               if (person.url && person.url.length > 0) {
                 appendPre(person.names[0].url)
               } else {
                 appendPre("No display name found for connection.");
               }
             }
           } else {
             appendPre('No connections found.');
           }
         });
      }
```

Comment: I don't want the current user's profile picture, I want to get a profile picture based on someone's email address. I'm displaying a list of emails, and I want to display their avatars.

Comment: Have you tried going through Gravatar api?   Google will only give you the information on the currently authenticated user.

Comment: Yes, I have. It doesn't really have that many results. Alsom if so, how does Gmail itself fetch avatars?

Comment: As i stated there is no way to get the gmail AVATARS of a random user.  please read the section **Get image of the sender of an email**

Comment: Would the -1 please comment.  Explaining in detail why something is not possible is not really a valid reason for a -1 IMO

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for, but it seems to be the only solution. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Unfortunately everything is not possible when you are dealing with user privacy.   Even things that sound like a really simple thing and great idea at the time.

Answer (score 5):

The currently accepted answer isn't entirely correct, as there absolutely is a Google API which exposes Gmail Avatars - as well as the user's first- and/or Lastname, as long as the user has configured any publically.

Although I have so far been unable to find the actual API endpoint you can use to achieve this, I did come across [avatarapi.com](https://www.avatarapi.com).

As stated on their website:

> This API uses public profile information provided by Google, via a publicly exposed Google data source to determine the name and profile image of the user.

They have a fallback to Gravatar. I'd also love to find out where this 'Google Data source' they use is located.

Comment: This doesn't work. I tried it with my Gmail address and all I got back was a silhouette image.

Comment: Tried it today with 4 different profiled. Today it worked partially. My own gmail and also the wordpress fallback for a diffent email worked. I also administrate a Google Workspace. I tried 5 emails 3 worked, 2 not, even if they all had pictures. I have no clue why, but you can just try on the start page with some emails.

Comment: I got far better results. They claim to have now more than a billion records on their database, and I've tried a few of my addresses, some of which registered with Gravatar, others not registered at all (except on the mail provider they've been registered on, e.g. Yahoo). I've got a *lot* of addresses :-) and I'd guess that about 80%-90% were correctly identified. Also, I was surprised at the sheer speed of this API! No wonder it's a paid service (no free tier — after 100 API calls as demo/test, you're starting to get billed for usage).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that google shares that info with anyone without permission .
You have to create a profile for every user and take the profile image only once when the user registers in your platform by the Google oauth 
Check this info 
https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in-oauth

Answer (score 2):

### Gravatar

It is possible that the user associated with that email address has signed up for [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/). In that case, you can easily obtain the Gravatar avatar.

You need to get the md5 of the email first, then

```
var email = "youremail@gmail.com",
    size = 80; 
yourImg.src = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + MD5(email) + '.jpg?s=' + size;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a4g8s5y2/1/

Comment: sry... I though it was just about gravatars

Comment: That's a useful resource, the link!

Comment: This question was asking how to obtain the Google profile pic, not the Gravatar profile pic.